# hibernate configuration exception

Tags: java, hibernate, exception, config

**StackTrace:**

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.tutorial.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:20)
    at org.hibernate.tutorial.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:9)
    at org.hibernate.tutorial.EventManager.createAndStoreEvent(EventManager.java:23)
    at org.hibernate.tutorial.EventManager.main(EventManager.java:16)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.tutorial.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:14)
    ... 3 more
```

**my hibernate config：**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping resource="org/hibernate/tutorial/domain/Event.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**my code：**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build());
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
public class EventManager {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventManager mgr = new EventManager();

        if (args[0].equals("store")) {
            mgr.createAndStoreEvent("My Event", new Date());
        }

        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
    }

    private void createAndStoreEvent(String title, Date theDate) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        Event theEvent = new Event();
        theEvent.setTitle(title);
        theEvent.setDate(theDate);
        session.save(theEvent);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure it's related to the exception, but accessing a MySql database with a HSQL driver doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Please change your connection driver, use com.mysql.jdbc.Driver for connecting to MySQL

Answer (score 0):

Your sessionfactory property names are incorrect. They should be

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
```

Note the property name is `hibernate.`

Comment: My configuration from the official document.the property name is hibernate.cfg.xml.